# Removing falsy values from a array leaves me with null values. How to Improve my code?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to remove the falsy values from an array. I tried usign typeOf and Boolean, but that would leave me with null values inside my array. How can I improve my code?

```
function bouncer(arr) {
    var myarr=[];
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        if(typeof arr[i] === 'boolean' || arr[i]=== 0 || arr[i]==="")
        {
            delete arr[i];
        }

    }
    return arr;
}

bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9]);
```

The outout from this code:

```
([7, "ate", null, null, 9])
```

How can I improve this code ? Why does typeOf ==='boolean' not delete 0 and null string "".

Update: The code should satisfy the below criteria.

```
bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9]) should return [7, "ate", 9].
bouncer(["a", "b", "c"]) should return ["a", "b", "c"].
bouncer([false, null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""]) should return [].
```

Thank you

Comment: You can't `delete` from arrays like that. Just create a new array and push on the valid values.

Comment: What output do you actually expect from that array? Given that `typeof arr[i] === 'boolean'` isn't going to differentiate between `true` and `false`.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli why can't I delete the values ? If the values are deleted, the array will be left with the right elements in the array.

Comment: @DavidThomas I would like to delete all the items that give Boolean(val) = True. Can you extend on why `typeOf==boolean` does not give true or false?

Comment: Because `true` and `false` are both Boolean values; if you want to test for `true` then test for `arr[i] === true`.

Comment: @Nodnin `delete` removes the value from that index, but it doesn't change the indexes of all the elements after it.

Comment: PS. You have code that isn't being used `var myarr=[];`

Comment: @Endless, I don't know know what you mean by "you have code". MY CODE contains an empty array that I defined because I thought I should push the values into that array. But the earlier version had errors. The code above produced a result with null values.

Comment: Also, why was the question downvoted ? I'm asking because, I'd like to know what to ask the right question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be as simple as this?

```js
var arr = [7, "ate", "", false, 9, "a", "b", "c", false, null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""];
var result = arr.filter(a=>a);

// [7, "ate", 9, "a", "b", "c"]

console.log(document.body.innerHTML = result);
```

Comment: What does a=> a mean ?

Comment: @Nodnin `=>`is the new [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) It's almost same as writing `function(a){ return a }`

Answer (score 0):

```
var newArr = [];
arr.forEach(function(element) {
    if (element != false)
        newArr.push(element);
});
return newArr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try if (!arr[i]){arr.splice(i,1)}

Comment: This will skip elelements, because splicing out an element moves all the following elements down, and then `i++` will skip the element that took its place.

Comment: Yes, well, then push to a new array in else statement. Or you could do arr.filter(function(val){ return val;})

Comment: That's what the other answers show. You should either edit your answer or delete it.

Comment: I don't know what is other answer, but that is mine, i have not cheated.

Comment: The answer by Endless uses `.filter`, the answer by Tennyson H uses `push`.